# Problema al colocar varios JLabel en JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, jframe, netbeans-8.2

Tengo un problema que no logro detectar que es lo que está pasando a la hora de colocar algunos Jlabels con imágenes dentro de un JFrame, los he logrado colocar "Correctamente", con excepción de siempre el último label, lo coloca en una posición de X y Y, que en no tiene sentido, les dejo el código necesario y una imagen de lo que me hace. Espero alguien pueda ayudarme llevo horas con este problema sin poder resolverlo, de ante mano gracias.

Este es el código de la clase del JFrame con los labels:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Tablero extends JFrame{   
    private Inicio origen;        
    public Tablero() {
       this.setSize(816, 710);
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       this.setResizable(false);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {            
          JLabel p=new JLabel();
          p.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\tablero\\"+i+".png"));            
          p.setBounds(136*i, 554, 136, 136);             
          this.add(p);
       }        
}
```

PD. De esta clase creo el objeto y visualizo por medio de otro JFrame simple de iniciar. Las imágenes que contienen los labels tienen nombres numéricos para facilitarme el acceso a ellas.

[image: Ejemplo de como coloca los JLabel en el Frame]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto un **JFrame** tiene como **LayoutManager** un **BorderLayout**, y por defecto nos coloca los *componentes centrados*.

Para no tener problemas como los que tu tienes, lo mejor es que **anules** ese **LayoutManager** con **setLayout();**

```
this.setLayout(null);
```

Ahora ya te debería funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me funcionó perfecto.

Comment: Un placer poder ayudar :)